# Infinite Time Vs. Finite Matter and Energy

Tags: cosmology

Okay, so I'm hoping someone with much more physics knowledge than me can shed some light on an odd discussion that I had with my brother some years ago. I've heard similar ideas, but nothing quite like what we came up with.

I'll try to make this as understandable as possible. If there is only a finite amount of matter and energy in the universe (although a massive and mind boggling amount) but time is infinite... does that present the possibility that all things are (in an even more massively mind boggling length of time) destined to repeat exactly over and over? Like this exact moment or all of our exact lives and experiences? I'm not asking this with any spiritual or religious undertones. I'm not at all religious and don't believe in such magical, nonsense. I'm asking this from a purely physics and time basis.

The best example we could come up with is this... the lottery seems almost impossible to win because the odds are so staggering. But if the odds are one in ten billion to win, and you hold all the possible numbers (the infinity of time vs finite number of matter) it's inevitable that you will win. Correct?  So, if time is infinite (so it's holding all the numbers) is it not inevitable that eventually everything will have to repeat due to a limited amount of options? No matter how many quadrillion of quadrillion aeons need to pass for things to find themselves in the same orientations and states electrically, all options would have to be cycled through and eventually exhausted. And once that happens some repetition of some kind has to start because all the possible combinations would have existed already?

Comment: Time is not infinite. Time as we are defining it has existed for roughly 13.8 billion years. Whether there was anything resembling a time variable before that is unknown. And with that your mind boggling question ends in a whimper at the event horizon of the big bang. The general idea of recurrence is an old one (19th century, to be precise) and it only occurs in the realm of classical mechanics, where a system with a finite phase space volume necessitates that its future trajectory will always return arbitrarily close to its past. This corner case does neither exist in open systems or in QM.

Comment: "Magical nonsense" talk along with an assumption of an eternal universe that only nominally changes. You know I love irony.

Comment: "Time as we are defining it" may be an extremely limited concept, given the resemblances between cosmological and black hole event horizons, and the persistent lack of agreement, between relativists and quantum physicists, as to time's resemblance (or lack of it) to those spatial dimensions within which we can willfully move.  Even within our (somewhat) "observable" region, "we" are on only one side of at least 90-odd separations of causality, surrounding astrophysically-confirmed black holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you are referring to is [Poincaré recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem). The idea is that if a closed system has only a finite number of possible states then it must eventually return to a state that is has been in before.

However the universe is not a closed system with a finite number of states and the recurrence theorem does not apply to it. For example the average density of the universe is decreasing with time. The observable universe will never return to a state just like its state right now because its density will never again be as high as it is right now. So the answer is that no the universe will not eventually repeat.

There are a couple of complications that I suppose we ought to mention. I have assumed that the universe will expand forever, but there have been suggestions it [could eventually recollapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch) and my even [oscillate in some cyclical fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology). However the physics behind these theories is so speculative that it's hard to say anything concrete about them.

It's also suggested that if the universe is infinite there will be [repetitions in space (rather than time)](http://phys.org/news/2013-01-dont-infinite-scientists.html). For example if you travel far enough you'll find another copy of yourself. Again, while these ideas are fun the physics behind them is not convincing enough for most of us to take them seriously.

Comment: I think even if we assume a cyclical universe quantum mechanics probably eliminates the recurrence in a classical sense and so do Lyapunov exponents in Hamiltonian mechanics. Even two perfectly identically prepared versions of the universe (within the limits of QM and thermodynamics) can not have the identical future if we take QM/TD seriously because the number of possible future evolutions is exponentially large than the current size of the state vector. I think Poincare and colleagues were very naive about an operational definition of "future".

Comment: @ John Rennie Because there is astrophysical evidence that causally-separated regions (black holes) form, and because there have been cosmologies hypothesized (such as Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion") which are consistent with the CMB data and provide plausible evidence that smaller versions resembling themselves may exist within such regions, I can't quite see how the possibility of Poincare recurrence can be ruled out (any more than it can be proven), unless there's some universal (not local) limit on divisibility itself. Is there one?

Comment: The form of recurrence visualized by the OP, & discussed by John Rennie, may be simpler and probably older than the recurrence formalized by Poincaré in 1890, which would include it but extend (as discussed in the Wiki "Poincaré recurrence") to arbitrarily exact copies, including copies of our observable region as it is now, regardless of whether it's presently expanding.  Altho disputed by Laura Mersini-Houghton, the full-blown version has purportedly had some experimental support even from quantum physicists, as discussed at https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/02/180222145053.htm .

Comment: In fact, it does turn out to be older:  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Auguste_Blanqui , and his 1871 book titled "L'Eternité par les astres".